# add uniq clause based on year of column with type date mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Is it possible to make a column unique based on just the year? For example:

```
ALTER TABLE groups ADD UNIQUE INDEX uniqcombo (group_id, YEAR('group_year'));
```

I tried the above query but it's giving me syntax errors near `'group_year'))`.

Is this possible or do I have to separate the year into its own column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in MySQL, you would need a separate column for the year alone.